# How to use JavaScript to set multiple strings to a css property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please note that I'm asking about multiple strings, not multiple properties.

More specifically, I'm looking for a javascript/jquery way to change [grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) property.

This property can take multiple strings as the value. For example:

```
grid-template-areas: "a b b"
                     "a c d";
```

Comment: Wrap the value in backticks or mask the quotes (or use another type of quote as delimiter): `el.style.gridTemplateAreas = \`"a c b" "a c d"\`;` https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/w96c7ruL/

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you need to include the double quotes within the new `grid-template-areas` value. As such you need to delimit the new string with single quotes. Try this:

```
$('#example-element').css('grid-template-areas', '"a b b" "a b b" "a c c"');
```

Note that this CSS rule only works in modern browsers (ie. everything except IE and older versions of Edge, <= 15)

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#example-element').css('grid-template-areas', '"a b b" "a b b" "a c c"');
});
```

```css
#example-element {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: .75em solid;
  padding: .75em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, minmax(40px, auto));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  grid-template-areas: "a a a" "b c c" "b c c";
}

#example-element :nth-child(1) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
  border: 3px solid #00f;
  grid-area: a;
}

#example-element :nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 200, .2);
  border: 3px solid #663399;
  grid-area: b;
}

#example-element :nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rgba(94, 255, 0, .2);
  border: 3px solid green;
  grid-area: c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-container">
  <div id="example-element" class="transition-all">
    <div>One (a)</div>
    <div>Two (b)</div>
    <div>Three (c)</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Change layout</button>
```